# Combining two switch cases in reasonML

Tags: reason

```
| (true, Select(true)) => true
| (false, Select(false)) => false
```

How can I combine these two in a switch statement with generic type?

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're asking for here. What do you mean by "combine", and what do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: Instead of writing two cases, is there a way to write a case such that
| (variantA, Select(VariantA)) => VariantA

Comment: What would be the point of that? If you're comparing against the value you want to extract, that means you already have it. Unless I misunderstand your code, since it's not really valid of course. A more detailed explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @a-c-sreedhar-reddy if the answer we provided in the Discord didn't work, please let us know.

Comment: Post the answer! If no one else does @a-c-sreedhar-reddy you can do it too. Stackoverflow is for everyone to find answers!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the patterns that you match against in a switch statement have to be 'linear' (ie, the variants inside the patterns should only appear once):

See https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html

> A pattern must necessarily be linear, that is, no given variable can occur more than once inside the pattern being matched. Thus, we might have hoped to be able to write:
>
> ```
> # let equal c = match c with 
>     (x,x) -> true   
>   | (x,y) -> false;; Characters 35-36: This variable is bound several times in this matching
> ```
>
> But this would have required the compiler to know how to carry out
> equality tests. Yet this immediately raises numerous problems. If we
> accept physical equality between values, we get a system which is too
> weak, incapable of recognizing the equality between two occurrences of
> the list [1; 2], for example. If we decide to use structural equality,
> we run the risk of having to traverse, ad infinitum, circular
> structures.

Note that ReasonML is just an alternative syntax for OCaml, so the above also holds for Reason. `match` is just the OCaml version of `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to combine the two cases generically using a `when` guard:

```ml
let f = (a, b) =>
  switch (a, b) {
  | (a, Select(b)) when a == b => a
  };
```

However, note that this isn't exhaustive, and you haven't specified what should be returned in the case that `a != b`. To avoid the non-exhaustiveness warning, and crash at runtime, you need to add another case to cover that.

Answer (score -1):

Following can be a solution for your problem. The operation *a&&b* depends on what logic you want the block to follow. I took a reasonable assumption that you wanted to perform AND operation. If you provide other possible conditions then this can be refined.

```
let getSelectionResponse = x => switch(x){ | (a, Select(b)) => a&&b};
```

[Tried it here](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=C4TwDgpgBAzhA2EDGwoF4oB8DKDnAAoAjAexPgEoBuAKEVQHMJhdEUBLEgOwCUIYw3OOigAPdAD5YAd3bAkACwKiKAbyxQCAQwA0UVvmIUKkqFoBk5ogF9aAKRgA6eCQYEmLPB258BQiAQEAGZa8HB6BijBoXDGxlRAA)